# How to incorporate the Java 3D library into eclipse in Mac?

Tags: java, macos, java-3d

I am a new user to Mac, having previously used Windows for programming. I just installed the Java 3D zip file from:
https://java3d.java.net/binary-builds.html
The zip file is now in my Finder and I don't know how to incorporate the library into Eclipse so that I can use it. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the obsolete unmaintained version of Java3D 1.5 provided by Oracle. Rather follow my detailed instructions for Java3D 1.6.0:
http://jogamp.org/wiki/index.php/Downloading_and_installing_Java3D

I advise you to read this if you don't understand why I speak about Oracle:
http://jogamp.org/wiki/index.php/Java3D_Overview

By the way, Java3D 1.7 will support Android too unlike the version you downloaded ;) Big kudos to Phil :)